# How to delete S3 Folder containing whitespaces and special character

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

as we've had an security audit fey days ago, the testing person created some very suspicious folders in our S3 Bucket. As a result, I'm currently not able to remove those folders.
At the moment there are two left and I'm struggeling with the delete syntax here - maybe you can help me:

[image]

[image]

What I already tried was to use this syntax in the CLI with escaping the white spaces, but that didn't work out:

```html
aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/mypath/events/events=Guide\ BCC:z66rktgbiq4ysb8u3gwgv0ih3891xwvkndb5yvmk@burpcollaborator.net\ oxl:\ c
```

Maybe someone is able to help me with the right syntax here?

Edit: When I list the buckets, I get the following result:
[image]

Comment: Did you try using double quote  ? e.g. aws s3 rm "s3://mybucket___events=Guide> BCC:503___" ?

Comment: That Syntax seems to work, it says :
delete: s3://mypath/events/events=Guide BCC:z66rktgbiq4ysb8u3gwgv0ih3891xwvkndb5yvmk@burpcollaborator.net oxl: c
-------
But folder is still there in the console :(

Comment: Does it have files in them?

Comment: Nope, it's totaly empty. I also tried with --recursive but that didn't work too. If I copy a file into that folder and try do delte it a second time, the folder is duplicated ?!?!

Comment: Did you try aws s3api delete-bucket ? (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-bucket.html) How did you create a bucket with the space ? I tried but AWS doesn't seem to be like it.

Comment: @Shuki - there's very important information in the bucket, so i'm not allowed to delete it completely- the creation was made by a thrid party software of an security auditor - I think he created these folders with a kafka stream.

Comment: From the image, it looks like it has newline characters!

Comment: Hi, I saw that too and tried: 
aws s3 rm "s3://bucketpath/events/events=Guide"$'\n'"BCC:z66rktgbiq4ysb8u3gwgv0ih3891xwvkndb5yvmk@burpcollaborator.net"$'\n'"oxl: c"           ------ But that didn't work either

Comment: Have you tried deleting the object/folder via the Amazon S3 management console?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - of course, that was my first try. It simply happens: Nothing. If I click delete the window refreshes and the folder is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to delete the object with a bit of code like this:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for object in s3.Bucket('bucket-name').objects.all():
    if '@burpcollaborator.net' in object.key:
        object.delete()
```

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your answer, it helped me to delete this folders. I solved it with the following code: 
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

for x in s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='mybucket',Prefix='mypath/events/').get('Contents'):
    if '\r' in x.get('Key') or '\n' in x.get('Key'):
        print(x.get('Key').replace('\r','|').replace('\n','@'))
s3_client.delete_object(Bucket='mybucket',Key=x.get('Key'))

Answer (score -1):

If any other is looking for a solution in aws cli, include the prefix and file in a single quotes like below.

aws s3 rm 's3://mybucket/mypath/events/test file.txt'